# Lottie animation going over header

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, lottie, tailwind-css

You can check what is going on in [www.dynamicpoa.com](https://dynamicpoa.com)

Just scroll and you'll see that everything is working properly, except the SVG animation (Lottie) that is going over the header. In both pages ("/" and "/cursos").

Anyone have a hint on how to fix it?

I've tried changing header position to 'fixed' and 'sticky' but nothing seems to work. I've tried to change the properties of the div that holds the animation aswell.

Appreciate your time.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to set a `z-index` for your `header` or `.sticky` class, like this:

```
.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add **z-index:10** to header container: element class:

```
sticky top-0 bg-white shadow
```

Add **z-index:1** to animation container: element class:

```
width:500px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;z-index: 1;outline:none; z1
```